# How to use rocket on stable release of Rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-rocket

I am trying to use stable version of `rustc` to compile a rocket web application. `rocket` crate compiles fine but I would like to use a static file server from `rocket_contrib`. My `Cargo.toml` file looks like this:

```
[dependencies]
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.1"

[dependencies.rocket_dyn_templates]
version = "0.1.0-rc.1"
features = ["handlebars"]

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4.10"
default-features = false
features = ["serve"]
```

I get the following error when I try to run `cargo build` :

```
Error: Pear requires a 'dev' or 'nightly' version of rustc.
Installed version: 1.52.1 (2021-05-09)
Minimum required:  1.31.0-nightly (2018-10-05)
```

Comment: To know how to setup stable version of rocket rust and run [Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682054/how-to-return-json-as-a-response-in-rust-rocket-with-auto-field-deserialising/70904135#70904135)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Starting from version 0.5 of Rocket, you are not expected to use `rocket_contrib`, because this one was split into features which are either already in the core crate or moved to separate crates. The notes from [this revision](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/commit/5a4e66ec439411d30f16e5c045f8e4986f5883a4) (see also [issue 1659](https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/issues/1659)) provide a few more details:

> This follows the completed graduation of stable contrib features into
> core, removing 'rocket_contrib' in its entirety in favor of two new
> crates. These crates are versioned independently of Rocket's core
> libraries, allowing upgrades to dependencies without consideration for
> versions in core libraries.
>
> 'rocket_dyn_templates' replaces the contrib 'templates' features. While
> largely a 1-to-1 copy, it makes the following changes:
>
> - the 'tera_templates' feature is now 'tera'
> - the 'handlebars_templates' feature is now 'handlebars'
> - fails to compile if neither 'tera' nor 'handlebars' is enabled
>
> 'rocket_sync_db_pools' replaces the contrib 'database' features. It
> makes no changes to the replaced features except that the `database`
> attribute is properly documented at the crate root.

In short, you will need to migrate your code away from `rocket_contrib`. Better guidelines may become available once v0.5 is definitely released, but until then, you may look for the features once available in `rocket_contrib` in the [core documentation and respective Cargo feature list](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/index.html#features).

Comment: As noted in https://github.com/SergioBenitez/Rocket/blob/v0.5-rc/CHANGELOG.md#contrib-graduation the `serve` component from `rocket_contrib` is now implemented in `rocket` by https://api.rocket.rs/v0.5-rc/rocket/fs/struct.FileServer.html