# Can't resolve `Responder<'_, '_>` is not implemented for `rocket_contrib::json::Json<MyStruct>`

Tags: json, rust, serde, rocket

I'm trying to return Json data with a rocket handler. I've seen many other posts with the same issue, where the solution for basically everyone where that they hadn't implemented serde::Deserialize/serde::Serialize. Does anyone have a solution?

[rocket_contrib docs](https://api.rocket.rs/v0.4/rocket_contrib/json/struct.Json.html#sending-json)

```
use rocket_contrib::json::Json;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct MyStruct;

pub fn get_timestamps(pool: &State<Pool>) -> Json<MyStruct> {
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Responder<'_, '_>` is not implemented for `rocket_contrib::json::Json<MyStruct>`
```

Cargo.toml

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.4"
bytes = "1"
mysql = "*"
dotenv = "0.15.0"
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
serde_derive = "1.0.127"
diesel = "1.4.7"
chrono = "0.4.19"
serde_json = "1.0"
rocket = "0.5.0-rc.1"

[dependencies.rocket_contrib]
version = "0.4"
default-features = false
features = ["json"]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return JSON as a response in Rust Rocket with auto field deserialising?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68682054/how-to-return-json-as-a-response-in-rust-rocket-with-auto-field-deserialising)

Comment: You are using rocket v5, rocket_contrib is for rocket v4.

Answer (score 3):

Since now we are at rocket v5 (the `rocket_contrib` crate was valid only for rocket v4), and checking that `Cargo.toml` have these dependencies:

```ini
...

[dependencies]
rocket = { version = "0.5.0-rc.2", features = ["json"] }
serde = "1.0.152"

...
```

To use the `Json` struct apply the following trait to `MyStruct` struct:

```rust
use rocket::serde::{json::Json, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize)]
pub struct MyStruct;

pub fn get_timestamps(pool: &State<Pool>) -> Json<MyStruct> {...}
```

Having pumped your `MyStruct` struct with the rocket methods, you should be able to work with `rocket::serde::json::Json`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to instead of

```
use rocket_contrib::json::Json;;
```

use this

```
use rocket::serde::json::Json;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: This isn't in the docs. https://docs.rs/rocket/latest/rocket/?search=serde